# InvalidValueError: The ipfs-repo-migrations package does not have all migration to migrate from version 10 to 11 at verifyAvailableMigrations

Tags: javascript, ipfs, js-ipfs

I get this error: **InvalidValueError: The ipfs-repo-migrations package does not have all migration to migrate from version 10 to 11 at verifyAvailableMigrations**  when I try to spin up ipfs-coord. Please does anyone have an idea on what I should do? Thanks in advance

Here's my code

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const BCHJS = require('@psf/bch-js')
const IpfsCoord = require('ipfs-coord')

async function start() {
  // Create an instance of bch-js and IPFS.
  const bchjs = new BCHJS()
  const ipfs = await IPFS.create()

  // Pass bch-js and IPFS to ipfs-coord when instantiating it.
  const ipfsCoord = new IpfsCoord({
    ipfs,
    bchjs,
    type: 'node.js'
  })

  await ipfsCoord.start()
  console.log('IPFS and the coordination library is ready.')
}
start()
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ipfs-coord-chat-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@psf/bch-js": "^4.20.26",
    "ipfs": "^0.55.4",
    "ipfs-coord": "^6.7.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this and found deleting the .jsipfs folder in my home directory solved it.

/home/tom/.jsipfs

Be warned though this will remove all previous data that was stored by your node so it would be wise to take a backup or find a way to roll back your dependencies and extract any crucial data.